# HDF5 Linking error 2

Tags: c++, c++11, hdf5

When I try to compile my program I get the following error. Any ideas?

```
g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -DOPENFOAM_PLUS=1712 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -O0 -fdefault-inline -ggdb3 -DFULLDEBUG -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/sampling/lnInclude   -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/meshTools/lnInclude  -IlnInclude -I. -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2.o -L/opt/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1712/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib \
    -lfiniteVolume -lsampling   -L/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/     -lhdf5_hl_cpp   -lhdf5_cpp  -lhdf5_hl   -lhdf5  -lsz    -lz     -ldl    -lm  -lOpenFOAM -ldl  \
    -ggdb3 -DFULLDEBUG -lm -o /local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/applications/bin/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2
Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2.o: In function `main':
/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/run/case13/solver/3DIBicoFoam_2.C:91: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/run/case13/solver/3DIBicoFoam_2.C:166: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/run/case13/solver/3DIBicoFoam_2.C:177: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/run/case13/solver/3DIBicoFoam_2.C:183: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/run/case13/solver/3DIBicoFoam_2.C:192: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::string const&) const'
Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2.o:/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/run/case13/solver/3DIBicoFoam_2.C:199: more undefined references to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::string const&) const' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/local/hulfeldl/OpenFOAM/hulfeldl-v1712/applications/bin/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/3DIBicoFoam_2] Error 1
```

Comment: does this path `/local/hulfeldl/hdf5/lib/` contain the hdf5 libraries?

Comment: Yes it does contain the hdf 5 libraries

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `h5c++`? It is just a wrapper around `g++` with all the linking taking care of.

Comment: Also you can minimize this example a lot, such that we could also try!